# EventToCommand is never triggered - MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have the following XAML code, where the user submits content everytime the enter-button is hit. The `EventToCommand` calls the `AddFieldCommand` method in ViewModel.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtFields" Text="{Binding FieldsTextProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Background="#FFCBEECD" AcceptsReturn="False" >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <iex:KeyTrigger Key="Enter">              
                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.AddFieldCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                    </iex:KeyTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

The Property `FieldsTextProperty` is defined in my MainViewModel.cs:

```
public string FieldsTextProperty { get; set; }
```

My ICommand for `AddFieldCommand` looks like this:

```
public ICommand AddFieldCommand { get; private set; }
```

and is initialized like this:

```
AddFieldCommand = new RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs>(AddField);
```

The method AddField looks like this:

```
 public void AddField(KeyEventArgs e)
 {
        FrameworkElement classDataVisualElement = (FrameworkElement)e.KeyboardDevice.Target;
        ClassData classDataModel = (ClassData)classDataVisualElement.DataContext;

        classDataModel.Fields.Add(FieldsTextProperty);

        FieldsTextProperty = "";

        RaisePropertyChanged("Fields");
  }
```

The code gets the current object and adds the content from the TextBox into the object.

This do not work and I cannot see why?
Nothing happen when I hit Enter and the `FieldsTextProperty` and `AddField` is never called

EDIT:
I have the following error in my Output window:
`'FieldsTextProperty' property not found on 'object' ''ClassData' (HashCode=46358046)'. BindingExpression:Path=FieldsTextProperty; DataItem='ClassData' (HashCode=46358046); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='txtFields'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')`

EDIT 2:
After several test - it seems what the problem is in the `FieldsTextProperty`. My old friend Console.Writeline("AddField Method") never disappoint ;)

EDIT 3:
Full (almost) XAML code:

```
<UserControl ..... >

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Class Name" Background="#FF96BB96" Foreground="Black" IsHitTestVisible="True">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.MouseDownClassDataCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.MouseMoveClassDataCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.MouseUpClassDataCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBlock>

    <StackPanel Opacity="{Binding DataContext.ModeOpacity, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF53855E" BorderThickness="1" Height="25"/>

        <!-- FIELDS ELEMENTS-->
        <Grid>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtFields" Text="{Binding FieldsTextProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Background="#FFCBEECD" AcceptsReturn="False" >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <iex:KeyTrigger Key="Enter">              
                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.AddFieldCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                    </iex:KeyTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBox>


            <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" Text="Insert Fields.." VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" Foreground="DarkGray">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtFields}" Value="">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>

        <DataGrid x:Name="PropertiesControl1" Height="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding ClassDatas}" HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Fields}" Header="" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <!-- More of the same code...-->

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: any binding erros ? 
look in your output window AddFieldCommand , I'm guessing it's null when the binding occurs .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a hunch .. Maybe the Command is null when the binding occurs .
try :

```
   private ICommand _addFieldCommand; 
   public ICommand AddFieldCommand 
   {
       get
       {
            if(_addFieldCommand == null)
                _addFieldCommand = new RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs>(AddField);
            return _addFieldCommand;  
       }
   }
```

XAML :

```
     <UserControl DataContext"={Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything.. But I have the following error:'FieldsTextProperty' property not found on 'object' ''ClassData' (HashCode=46358046)'. BindingExpression:Path=FieldsTextProperty; DataItem='ClassData' (HashCode=46358046); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='txtFields'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Comment: Then your DataContext is a ClassData instance and not the MainViewModel.
please show a shorted xaml of where your TextBox sits .

Comment: I have added a shorted XAML.

Comment: your UserControl's DataContext is an instance of ClassData , and not MainViewModel

Comment: How do I change the DataContext, so its an instance to MainViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
AddFieldCommand.CanExecute = true;
```

after you initialise the command

Comment: No matter where I place your code, I get an error from VS. Should it be placed in the Constructor, the method or?

Comment: It should be placed in the constructor after the line where you initialise your `RelayCommand` More info about `CanExecute` Found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @user1: CanExecute is a `Func<bool>`, it does not make sense to change it to `true`.